# Empty map when using px.choropleth mapbox

Tags: python, json, plotly, geojson, choropleth

I try to display a map using json but this is the first time and I am probably using it wrong because when using px.choropleth alone my map is showing.
But I would like to use px.choropleth mapbox for a more elaborate map.
Here is the code below

Thanks for your help

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib
import folium
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
import json
import plotly.io as pio

Final = pd.read_excel('/Users/Desktop/Data_Extract_From_Indicateurs_du_développement_dans_le_monde (3).xlsx')
DataSet.head()

worldmap = json.load(open("/Users/Desktop/countries.geojson",'r'))
worldmap['features'][1]['properties']

world_id_map = {}
for feature in worldmap['features']:
    feature['id'] = feature['properties']['ADMIN']
    world_id_map[feature['properties']['ISO_A3']] = feature['id']

world_id_map = json.loads(worldmap)
              
figmap = px.choropleth(Final, 
                              locations='Country Code', 
                              color='CO2 emissions',
                              color_continuous_scale="Algae",
                              animation_frame='Date', 
                              range_color=[20,10],
                              title='Worldwilde CO2 Emissions per habitant',
                              )

plot(figmap)

fig = go.Figure(go.Choroplethmapbox(geojson=world_id_map,
                                    locations=Final['Country Code'],
                                    z=Final['CO2 emissions'],
                                    colorscale='algae', zmin=0, zmax=35,
                                    colorbar_title = "CO2 emissions",
                                    marker_opacity=0.5, marker_line_width=0.2))
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="carto-positron")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})

plot(fig)
```

Answer (score 0):

- have simulated your data frame and dynamically sourced *heojson* from **GitHub**
- there is not need to manipulate the *geojson* all you need to do is pass the **featureidkey** parameter to link to **locations**
- have left code in place for producing **choropleth** and **choropleth_mapbox**

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.io as pio
import requests
import numpy as np

# Final = pd.read_excel('/Users/Desktop/Data_Extract_From_Indicateurs_du_développement_dans_le_monde (3).xlsx')
# DataSet.head()

# worldmap = json.load(open("/Users/Desktop/countries.geojson",'r'))
# get countries from internet...
worldmap = requests.get(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvkelso/natural-earth-vector/master/geojson/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.geojson"
).json()

# simulate dataframe,  don't to local file
Final = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Country Code": [f["properties"]["ADM0_A3"] for f in worldmap["features"]],
        "Date": np.tile(
            pd.date_range("1-jan-2015", freq="Y", periods=7).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), 100
        )[0 : len(worldmap["features"])],
        "CO2 emissions": np.random.uniform(10, 20, len(worldmap["features"])),
    }
)

figmap = px.choropleth(
    Final,
    locations="Country Code",
    color="CO2 emissions",
    color_continuous_scale="Algae",
    animation_frame="Date",
    range_color=[20, 10],
    title="Worldwilde CO2 Emissions per habitant",
)

figmap = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    Final,
    locations="Country Code",
    geojson=worldmap,
    featureidkey="properties.ADM0_A3",
    color="CO2 emissions",
    color_continuous_scale="Algae",
    animation_frame="Date",
    range_color=[20, 10],
    title="Worldwilde CO2 Emissions per habitant",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
).update_layout(mapbox={"zoom":2})

plot(figmap)
```